# How to resolve ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] when trying to connect to Tic Tac Toe game using socket programming from a different machine?

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, tic-tac-toe

I have built a Tic Tac Toe game using socket programming in Python, with a server and a client. The server is running on one machine and the client is running on a different machine. When trying to connect the client to the server using the socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) command and port WKP 5131, I keep getting the ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it error. How can I resolve this issue and successfully connect the client to the server?

I have already checked my firewall settings and even created a new rule to allow TCP connections on port 5131 for my server and client. Both the server and client are running on the same host and port and are working perfectly on the same machine. However, when trying to connect the client from a different machine, I still receive the 'ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]' error. Since it is only the client that is having trouble connecting, it couldn't be a high latency or congestion issue. How can I troubleshoot and fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the code.  What do you get when you run ```socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())```?

Comment: Hey there. Without posting any code, it's very difficult for us to help you with your issue. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on asking questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.